# Не двигается изображение мышью в JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

У меня в сцене есть объекты которые я хотел бы двигать мышкой. И Есть функция:

```
 @FXML
    void pressCard(MouseEvent event){
        ImageView node = (ImageView) event.getSource();
        xOffset = event.getSceneX();
        yOffset = event.getSceneY();

        System.out.println("@@@@@@@@@@@@ " + xOffset + ";" + yOffset + ";" + node);

        node.setOnMouseDragged( e -> {
            System.out.println("$$$$$" + e.getSceneX() + ";" + e.getSceneY());
                node.setX(e.getScreenX() - xOffset);
                node.setY(e.getScreenY() - yOffset);
        });
    }
```

Выводы тут только для проверки. Сама функция прикручена к действию onMousePressed

Я не понимаю почему это не работает, ведь точно так же я делаю с другим окном, что бы пользователь мог двигать окно и там это работает -_-

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать уже готовый класс. [Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46696687/8684911) ссылка на хорошее решение. Чтобы использовать его, просто напишите:

```
Draggable.Nature nature = new Draggable.Nature(node);
```

Будет интересно - почитайте [документацию](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/events/filters.htm) (там тоже приводится свой пример решения). Удачи!